# Issues creating a nuget package referening Xamarin Forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

I'm creating a nuget package that is refercing a number of different packages for the platforms.

I don't sem to be able to reference Xam.Forms.Platform. from the various ItemGroups as well as packages I've added via nuget for specific platforms.

I'm using this as a reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-packages-for-xamarin and my csproj is this

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras/2.0.54">

<PropertyGroup>
<!--Work around so the conditions work below-->
<TargetFrameworks></TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition=" '$(OS)' == 
    'Windows_NT'">netstandard2.0;Xamarin.iOS10;MonoAndroid90;uap10.0.16299</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition=" '$(OS)' != 
    'Windows_NT'">netstandard2.0;Xamarin.iOS10;MonoAndroid90</TargetFrameworks>

<AssemblyName>Plugin.Mobile.Xamarin</AssemblyName>
<RootNamespace>Plugin.Mobile.Xamarin</RootNamespace>
<PackageId>Plugin.Mobile.Xamarin</PackageId>

<Product>Plugin.Mobile.Xamarin</Product>
<AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
<AssemblyFileVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyFileVersion>
<Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
<PackageVersion>1.0.0.0</PackageVersion>
<PackOnBuild>true</PackOnBuild>
<NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
<LangVersion>default</LangVersion>
<DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);</DefineConstants>

<UseFullSemVerForNuGet>false</UseFullSemVerForNuGet>
<EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>

<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
<DebugType>portable</DebugType>


<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Debug' ">
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<GenerateDocumentationFile>false</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Release' ">
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="**\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform" Version="6.2.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.5.3.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.7.0.1179" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material" Version="4.7.0.1179" />
<PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views.Forms" Version="2.80.1" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<None Update="Langs.Designer.cs">
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DependentUpon>Langs.resx</DependentUpon>
</None>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<None Update="shared\Langs.Designer.cs">
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DependentUpon>Langs.resx</DependentUpon>
</None>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
<PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views.Forms">
  <Version>2.80.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.5.3.2" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'uap10.0.16299'">
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform" Version="6.2.9" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
<PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views.Forms">
  <Version>2.80.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.7.0.1179" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material" Version="4.7.0.1179" />
<SDKReference Include="WindowsMobile, Version=10.0.16299.0">
  <Name>Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP</Name>
</SDKReference>

<Compile Include="**\UWP*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'Xamarin.iOS10'">
<Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Xamarin.iOS.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
<PackageReference Include="EasyTipView">
  <Version>1.0.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views.Forms">
  <Version>2.80.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.7.0.1179" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material" Version="4.7.0.1179" />

<Compile Include="**\iOS*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('MonoAndroid')) ">
<Reference Include="Mono.Android">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views.Forms">
  <Version>2.80.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Tooltips">
  <Version>1.0.7</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors" Version="4.5.0" />
<Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.7.0.1179" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material" Version="4.7.0.1179" />

<Compile Include="**\Droid*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Any ideas on why I can't include or reference these packages?

The errors I'm seeing are the likes of

[image: Error imge]

Comment: Have you resolved the issue then please can you share your GitHub repo link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas on why I can't include or reference these packages?

The issue is caused by the project template [Cross-Platform .NET Standard Library Plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-packages-for-xamarin#create-the-project-structure-and-abstraction-code).

**To be precise**, this is due to the design of this special project template.

[As the document said](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-packages-for-xamarin#write-your-platform-specific-code), you should use the corresponding platform namespace in `xxx.<PLATFORM>.cs` file of each platform project.

**Suggestion**

From your description, the namespaces you are using are all related to **Android**, so you should add these in the file `<project_name>.andoroid.cs`which targets to **MonoAndroid90**.

And if you input them in the file called `apple.cs`,`uwp.cs` or others, the template is unable to identify them.

[image]

And you can see `<project_name>.andoroid.cs` file is connected with **MonoAndroid90**, so it can identify android namespaces and the same is true for other platform files.

**In addition**, if you still want your requirements, you should connect with the extension's author to reflect the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your `TargetFrameworks` become like this

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;Xamarin.iOS10;MonoAndroid90</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">uap10.0.16299;$(TargetFrameworks)</TargetFrameworks>
```